# How is google call screen streaming audio to an incoming call?

Tags: applications, calls, call-screening, call-recording

I have been trying to stream an on-device audio file to an incoming call, I am not able to achieve that. but it looks [google call screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4jOdVTkqS4) is having no problem streaming audio to an incoming call.

I just wanted to understand how are they achieving that, if it is fundamentally not possible?

Comment: Welcome. This site is for end users of Android. The link you provided is to Google's call screen which has no streaming audio, just Google intercepting the call and identifying possible spam numbers and voice transcription. Programming Android questions should be on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android Oddly your accounts aren't linked as I see your post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59127262/295004

Comment: Google assistant is sending feedback also the caller

Comment: And yeah, i have posted the question in SO also, i was not sure which is the right place to ask the question.